# Achieving `call_user_func_array` in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I accomplish http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php in ruby?

So I can do this:

```
class App
    def foo(a,b)
        puts a + b
    end
    def bar
        args = [1,2]
        App.send(:foo, args) # doesn't work
        App.send(:foo, args[0], args[1]) # does work, but does not scale
    end
end
```

Comment: Removed the `php` tag as this is not a php question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try exploding the array

```
App.send(:foo, *args)
```

Comment: Just for completeness: 'Exploding' an array means that the interpreter will send all items in args as separate arguments. The unary `*` is called the __splat__ operator in Ruby idioms.

Comment: And it doesn't just work on arrays. If it's not an array already, it will be converted to one using `to_ary` and `to_a`.