# How to pass array as separated arguments to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This seems close to what I need but it doesn't work for me.

[Achieving `call_user_func_array` in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119352/achieving-call-user-func-array-in-ruby)

I have a list as Constant

```
TYPE = %w(:groups :projects)
```

I'm using https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize on my RelatedList model which has

```
enumerize :list_type, in: %w(groups projects), scope: :type
```

So as per documentation on the github page,

```
RelatedList.type(:groups) # returns all RelatedList of type 'groups'
```

However, I want to get all RelatedList contained in my constant TYPE

so I tried

```
RelatedList.type(TYPE) # doesn't work
RelatedList.send(:type, TYPE) # doesn't work
RelatedList.send(:type, *TYPE) # doesn't work.
```

RelatedList.type expects a list of separate arguments as symbols but what I have is an array of symbols.

How do I achieve that?

---

as per DNNX request in answer below, here is the full traceback.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/enumerize-bc01a5cb3c79/lib/enumerize/activerecord.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in _define_scope_methods!'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/enumerize-bc01a5cb3c79/lib/enumerize/activerecord.rb:34:in `map'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/enumerize-bc01a5cb3c79/lib/enumerize/activerecord.rb:34:in `block in _define_scope_methods!'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus/rails.rb:134:in `console'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:116:in `block in command'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:103:in `fork'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:103:in `command'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:80:in `block (3 levels) in go'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:80:in `fork'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in go'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in `each'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in `block in go'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in `loop'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in `go'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in `block (3 levels) in go'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in `fork'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in go'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in `each'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in `block in go'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in `loop'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in `go'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in `block (3 levels) in go'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in `fork'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in go'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in `each'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in `block in go'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in `loop'
    from /Users/kw/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in `go'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... *what I have is an array of symbols*

No, is not. This `TYPE = %w(:groups :projects)` is an array of two strings `':groups'` and `':projects'`, not an array of symbols.

Try this instead:

```
TYPE = %w(groups projects)
RelatedList.type(*TYPE)
```

Or, if you is lucky and running your app on Ruby 2.0.0, use symbol array literal:

```
TYPE = %i(groups projects)
#=> [:groups, :projects]
```

Comment: why not `%i(groups projects)` ?

Comment: I get ```NoMethodError: undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass```

RelatedList.type(:groups, :projects) work fine.

Comment: nope. even with symbol array, it doesn't work. 
```rb(main):002:0> RelatedList.type(TYPE)
NoMethodError: undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass
 from /Users/shivam/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/enumerize-bc01a5cb3c79/lib/enumerize/activerecord.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in _define_scope_methods!'
 from /Users/shivam/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/enumerize-bc01a5cb3c79/lib/enumerize/activerecord.rb:34:in `map'
```

Comment: RelatedList.type(*TYPE) works great! can you post it as answer? Also can you briefly explain what is the magic behind *TYPE? I mean what is it basically?

Comment: @DNNX how does *TYPE work if TYPE is defined in a class Content. i.e., I can only call Content::TYPE and not TYPE directly. I tried *Content::TYPE and Content::*TYPE but both of them failed.

Comment: `*Content::TYPE` should work fine. Could you show us the error?

Comment: `*` is a splat operator. What it basically does is it expands an array into a list of arguments. `f(*[x, y, z])` is the same as `f(x, y, z)`.